# how to decrypt gitlab api token from jenkins base using stage in pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Team, i am unable to decrypt the gitlab api token and not sure which class to call for it. any hint?

```
        stage('string (gitlab api token)') {
          steps {
            script {
              withCredentials([
                apiToken(
                  credentialsId: 'gitlab-api-token',
                  variable: 'GITLAB_API_TOKEN')
              ]) {
                print 'GITLAB_API_TOKEN=' + GITLAB_API_TOKEN
                print 'GITLAB_API_TOKEN.collect { it }=' + GITLAB_API_TOKEN.collect { it }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.MultiBinding is using symbol ‘apiToken’
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:570)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.UninstantiatedDescribable.instantiate(UninstantiatedDescribable.java:207)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:466)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerceList(DescribableModel.java:585)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:458)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
```

Comment: You are passing `apiToken` class to the `withCredentials` which is not a valid option, check again what is the type of your credentials - it should match one of the types listed in the bottom of [This Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) page.